# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS running very slow after update(Dual Boot Ubuntu and Windows 10)

Tags: 18.04, windows

I have been running dual boot of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and Windows 10 now for about 8 months but with no problems. Now yesterday i recieved notofication about updates in ubuntu and i went on and update it but after rebooting my pc, Ubuntu runs very slow with fan running like Hussein Bolt at all times and bluetooth can't turn on even does not show up its usual postion. But when i boot in windows and i restart back to ubuntu it seams the speed is fine. I have tried repairing grub, packages and so on but nothings seams to work. Please help me how can i fix this as it makes my life awful. Thanks

Edited:

`top` output:

```
%Cpu(s): 95.9 us,  4.1 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  4004128 total,   938560 free,  1569352 used,  1496216 buff/cache
KiB Swap:   975868 total,   975868 free,        0 used.  1900576 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                     
  815 root      20   0   71628  39112   4288 R  97.0  1.0   2:05.40 bluetoothd                                                                  
 2547 root      20   0  502708  92688  67560 S  95.1  2.3   0:18.65 packagekitd                                                                 
 4749 fadsoft   20   0 1199380 109748  31948 S   1.0  2.7   0:04.09 gnome-software                                                              
  823 message+  20   0   51688   6196   4032 S   0.7  0.2   0:00.98 dbus-daemon                                                                 
 3423 fadsoft   20   0 2218676 132888  92240 S   0.7  3.3   0:02.71 skypeforlinux                                                               
 3962 fadsoft   20   0  844664 191708 116640 S   0.7  4.8   0:07.74 chrome                                                                      
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.3  0.0   0:00.23 rcu_sched                                                                   
  855 root      20   0    4552    760    696 S   0.3  0.0   0:00.01 acpid                                                                       
  930 root      35  15   19312   5780   2424 S   0.3  0.1   0:00.58 preload                                                                     
 2690 fadsoft   20   0  581624  64560  46200 S   0.3  1.6   0:04.53 Xorg                                                                        
 2822 fadsoft   20   0 3376400 152152  72604 S   0.3  3.8   0:14.64 gnome-shell                                                                 
 3232 fadsoft   20   0  361708   7816   6392 S   0.3  0.2   0:00.21 ibus-daemon                                                                 
 3556 fadsoft   20   0 2321432 227676 112280 S   0.3  5.7   0:08.09 skypeforlinux                                                               
 4000 fadsoft   20   0  546800  83380  62064 S   0.3  2.1   0:01.56 chrome                                                                      
 4437 fadsoft   20   0  799892  36612  27352 S   0.3  0.9   0:00.46 gnome-terminal-                                                             
 4800 fadsoft   20   0   51328   4104   3428 R   0.3  0.1   0:00.18 top                                                                         
    1 root      20   0  160292   9452   6608 S   0.0  0.2   0:02.08 systemd                                                                     
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd                                                                    
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0                                                                 
    4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H                                                                
    5 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/u4:0                                                                
    6 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mm_percpu_wq                                                                
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.12 ksoftirqd/0                                                                 
    9 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh                                                                      
   10 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0                                                                 
   11 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/0                                                                  
   12 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/0                                                                     
   13 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/1                                                                     
   14 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/1                                                                  
   15 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/1                                                                 
   16 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.10 ksoftirqd/1
```

`free` output:

```
         total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:     4004128     1584296      910280    300876   1509552     1877544
Swap:    975868           0       975868
```

Comment: As with most other "my-ubuntu-seems-slow" questions, please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1173972/edit) your question to include output from `top` and `free` during a sluggish period.

Comment: I dont understand what you are saying, how can i get those outputs you talking about??

Comment: open a terminal and enter these commands  then copy and paste them in your question (use code brackets ` <- that is the backwards mark that is in the same key as ~ should be just above tab)
`top`
`free`
you need to do this when you notice Ubuntu is running slowly so that we can see what might be slowing it down.

Comment: Once you have collected the information requested from top and free in the terminal, click [edit] so you can edit your question and add the information. Please do not use Add Comment as Comments lose the formatting and the text is all lumped together; instead, use [edit].

Comment: I have edited the question but it seams my bluetooth drivers are misbehaving